# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, parsing, syntax-error, mysql-python, eof

I am trying to fetch the data from csv and insert it into mysql table .While trying that I am getting the `Syntax Error` . Please help me to sort out this error .

*code*

```
import csv
import MySQLdb as mdb
import ast
cr = csv.reader(open("tushar.csv","rb"))
k=0
con = mdb.connect('***', '***', '***', '****')
cur = con.cursor()
for row in cr:
    if k%2==0:
        t=row
        print t
    else:
        l1=row
        l=ast.literal_eval(l1[0])
        sql="INSERT INTO amazon_order  (orderno,mainStatus,stateCode,timeStamp,destZip,orderDate,cost) Values('%s','%s','%s')"%(t,l["status"],l["state_code"],l["processed_timestamp"],l["destination_zip"],l["odr_date"],l["cost"])
        print sql
        cur.execute(sql)
        con.commit()
    k+=1
if con:
    con.close()
```

*Error*

```
['497832']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linkedlist.py", line 14, in 
    l=ast.literal_eval(l1[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "", line 1
    {"status": "All items processed"
                                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

*tushar.csv*

```
497832
{"status": "All items processed", "state_code": "GA", "processed_timestamp": "2013/05/14 19:32:08 UTC", "destination_zip": "31028", "odr_date": "2013-05-13 00:00:00""cost": 54.08}
487870
{"status": "All items processed", "state_code": "CT", "processed_timestamp": "2013/03/11 22:15:43 UTC", "destination_zip": "06468", "odr_date": "2013-03-11 00:00:00","cost": 149.43}
and so on..
```

Comment: Your data is truncated, it appears.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using CSV. Your file isn't in a comma-separated values format. CSV splits the file lines into unparsable pieces.

Take

```
{"status": "All items processed", "state_code": "GA", "processed_timestamp": "2013/05/14 19:32:08 UTC", "destination_zip": "31028", "odr_date": "2013-05-13 00:00:00""cost": 54.08}
```

and split it on the ',' and you get a list:

```
['{"status": "All items processed"',
 '"state_code": "GA"',
 '"processed_timestamp": "2013/05/14 19:32:08 UTC"',
 (etc..)
```

That first line is looking kinda familiar.

Just open the file and read it line by line - skip the csv thing entirely.